# vstest.console.exe not finding google tests - but running exe with --gtest_list_tests does

Tags: googletest, vstest.console.exe

I'm trying to run google test using vstest.console.exe.

I'm wondering if there is a way to debug why vstest.console.exe is not finding google tests.

Here is some output running locally:

```
C:\Development\Source\Bentley.Reliability\oq.framework\Tests\Infrastructure.Native.Tests\bin\x64\Debug>vstest.console.exe Infrastructure.Native.Tests.exe /TestAdapterPath:c:\packages\GoogleTestAdapter.0.18.0\build\_common -- RunConfiguration.TreatNoTestsAsError=true /Platform:x64 /Configuration:Debug
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.3.0-preview-20220626-01 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in C:\Development\Source\Bentley.Reliability\oq.framework\Tests\Infrastructure.Native.Tests\bin\x64\Debug\Infrastructure.Native.Tests.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

C:\Development\Source\Bentley.Reliability\oq.framework\Tests\Infrastructure.Native.Tests\bin\x64\Debug>Infrastructure.Native.Tests.exe --gtest_list_tests
Running main() from C:\Development\Source\Bentley.Reliability\packages\gmock.1.11.0\lib\native\src\gtest\src\gtest_main.cc
RestoreDatabaseTests.
  RestoreDatabaseTest
  CreateSnapshotTest
  RestoreDatabaseBlankServerNameTest
  RestoreDatabaseBlankDatabaseNameTest
  RestoreDatabaseBlankUserNameTest
  RestoreDatabaseIncorrectPasswordTest
TestExceptions.
  InvalidActivityExceptionTest
  InvalidConfigurationExceptionTest
  InvalidSessionExceptionTest
  PlatformNotSupportedExceptionTest
  OQGenericObjectTest
  TestDynamicCast_IncorrectExceptionType_Returns_Null
TestConfigurationProxy.
  TestBasics
  TestUnmanagedSettings
TestKernelExecutionContextThreadStorage.
  TestKernelExecutionContextThreadLocalStorage
TestSqlUomListLoader.
  TestLoadUomsFromDatabase_Success
  TestMockAdapter_LoadUomsFromDatabase_Success
  TestMockAdapter_LoadUomsFromDatabase_FetchFails
  TestMockAdapter_LoadUomsFromDatabase_FetchFails_ValidateMessage
TestUOMListInterop.
  CreateUOMList_throws_on_null_loggingProxy
  CreateUOMList_throws_on_null_sqlAdapter
  oUOM_GetUOMS_asserts_on_null_kernelExecutionContext
  oUOM_GetUOMS_asserts_on_null_uomlist
  oUOM_GetUOMS_no_asserts_when_list_defined
MockConfigurationTests.
  TestGetValueFromFakeCollection
  TestGetValueFromEnvironment
  TestGetValueOrderPrecidence
  TestRemovingFakeValue
```

Comment: Do you need to add /TestAdapterPath ?

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right.  I entered this a long time ago and got past it.  If you want to enter it as an answer, I will accept it. @BruceAdams

Comment: I was actually wondering myself how to set /TestAdapterPath for gtest now that the adapter is built in. The location is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I will put how I got it working in DevOps yaml.

A similar approach could be used to the GoogleTestAdapter locally and have a known path to the test adapter.

e.g. $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GoogleTestAdapterPackage\GoogleTestAdapter\build_common - but replace $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) with your root folder.

One option is to run nuget install and exclude version ( so you don't get 3.17 etc in the path )

You could also run nuget install as a pre-build event.

```
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'Nuget install GoogleTestAdapter'
        inputs:
          command: 'custom'
          arguments: 'install GoogleTestAdapter -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GoogleTestAdapterPackage'

      - powershell: 'Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GoogleTestAdapterPackage\GoogleTestAdapter\build\_common\'
        displayName: 'List GoogleTestAdapter files for debugging purposes'
```

Then you can reference the path using something similar to pathtoCustomTestAdapters

```
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'Run ReliabilityUpdateService.IntegrationTests.exe'
        inputs:
          testAssemblyVer2: ReliabilityUpdateService.IntegrationTests.exe
          searchFolder: $(rootFolder)\tests\ReliabilityUpdateService.IntegrationTests\bin\$(buildPlatform)\$(buildConfiguration)
          testRunTitle: ReliabilityUpdateService.IntegrationTests.exe
          platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
          configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"
          pathtoCustomTestAdapters: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GoogleTestAdapterPackage\GoogleTestAdapter\build\_common'
```

Comment: I've put how I got it working in AzureDevops Yaml.  Similar approaches might be helpful when running locally.  @BruceAdams