# vstest task cannot find any tests when using google test executable in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, googletest, vstest

I have been trying to run tests using the vstest@2 task within azure devops pipelines and there are never any tests found when using the google test executable. I do have the test assembly specified to google test and Nuget restores google test in an earlier pipeline task.

Here is a snippet of my yaml

```
- task : VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'VSbuild'
  inputs :
    solution : '$(solution)'
    platform : '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration : ${{parameters.buildconfiguration}}


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    searchFolder:  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<ProjectRepo>'
    resultsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\UnitTesting.exe
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    pathtoCustomTestAdapters: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/GoogleTestAdapter'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: ${{parameters.buildconfiguration}}
```

UnitTesting.exe is the google test executable that is generated using the vsbuild@1 task just before.

Below is the output from the vstest task.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@D:\a\_temp\c4zmbclzr0a.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\UnitTesting.exe"
/Settings:"D:\a\_temp\2kvnbwgfz0c.tmp.runsettings"
/EnableCodeCoverage
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\GoogleTestAdapter"
Starting test execution, please wait...
2.391
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No settings file provided through env variable GTA_FALLBACK_SETTINGS
Warning: Using default settings.
Google Test Adapter: Test execution starting...
Found 0 tests in executable D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\UnitTesting.exe
##[error]Test discovery was cancelled after 30s for executable 'D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\UnitTesting.exe'
Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:31.6375081.
##[error]================
##[error]The following warnings and errors occured during test execution (enable debug mode for more information):
##[error]Test discovery was cancelled after 30s for executable 'D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\UnitTesting.exe'
No test is available in D:\a\1\s\<project repo>\UnitTesting.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Results File: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-CVJL4F2UTMJ_2022-12-19_22_25_03.trx
Attachments:
  D:\a\1\s\TestResults\e27d838c-1572-409c-886c-741d2b1a6e51\VssAdministrator_WIN-CVJL4F2UTMJ_2022-12-19.22_24_28.coverage
##[error]Test Run Failed.
Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.
**************** Completed test execution *********************
Test results files: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-CVJL4F2UTMJ_2022-12-19_22_25_03.trx
No Result Found to Publish 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-CVJL4F2UTMJ_2022-12-19_22_25_03.trx'.
Created test run: 1381422
Publishing test results: 0
Publishing test results to test run '1381422'.
TestResults To Publish 0, Test run id:1381422
Published test results: 0
Publishing Attachments: 2
Execution Result Code 1 is non zero, checking for failed results
Completed TestExecution Model...
##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
##[error]Error: The process 'D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.210.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
Finishing: VSTest
```

I know I can use the command line task and run the google test executable and publish pipeline results from there, but I want to be able to use code coverage with the vstest task.

Edit for comments:
When I run the following task just before the VSTest task I get output of all my tests.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: '"<project repo output directory>/UnitTesting.exe" --gtest_list_tests'
```

Final Edit:
I have determined that this specific problem may just be a limitation of google test adapter. In the google test adapter documentation it mentions that when running using VsTest.Console it is undefined if you can have debugging capabilities ([see here](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter#feature-availability)). Since the vstest@2 task is just a front end for VsTest.Console, it would not allow debug and code coverage collection. See the (vstest@2 documentation)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines#inputs] where it mentions you can direct it to a different vstest.console.exe to run a different version to see that it is just using vstest.console. Thanks for all the help in trying to get this to work.

Comment: Can you get the [code coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2022&tabs=cpp#analyze-code-coverage-from-the-command-line) result  on command line  from your local machine?

Comment: Please show `UnitTesting.exe --gtest_list_tests` output.

Comment: I am able to get a code coverage file using the command line on my local maching and doing UnitTesting.exe --gtest_list_tests gives me a huge list of tests, I have over 1000 tests in this project. 
'''
Req5Enabled01
Req5Enabled02
Req5Disabled01
Req5Disabled02
Req5Disabled03
Req5Enabled01
Req5Enabled02
'''

Comment: Try putting the exe ,GoogleTestAdapter files and dlls and in the same directory. Use  absolute directory.

Comment: @whatisdevops You could try to apply the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750442/vstest-console-exe-not-finding-google-tests-but-running-exe-with-gtest-list

Comment: Google Test Adapter in MSVC has an option to show additional debug info named *Print debug info*, possibly finding something similar will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that this specific problem may just be a limitation of google test adapter. In the google test adapter documentation it mentions that when running using VsTest.Console it is undefined if you can have debugging capabilities (see here). Since the vstest@2 task is just a front end for VsTest.Console, it would not allow debug and code coverage collection. See the (vstest@2 documentation)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines#inputs] where it mentions you can direct it to a different vstest.console.exe to run a different version to see that it is just using vstest.console. Thanks for all the help in trying to get this to work.